# Convert a function with 2 parameters into a lambda action

Tags: c#, lambda, action, assert

I want to test (with `using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`) that the top line of this test function causes a `DataMisalignedException` to be thrown.

```
namespace xxx.Services.SupplierApiTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class JsonSchemaValidatorTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void ShouldThrowOnBadPhoneNumber()
        {
            JsonSchemaValidator.validateAgainstJsonSchema(ProviderService.getErronousProviders(), "./provider-schema.json");
            Action<IList, string> myAction = (x, y) => JsonSchemaValidator.validateAgainstJsonSchema(x, y);
            Assert.ThrowsException<DataMisalignedException>(myAction);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I use `JsonSchemaValidator.validateAgainstJsonSchema` as an action, passing in the two arguments from the top line of the test? My attempt is in the code above but doesn't pass the two parameters.

Comment: I think you want `Assert.ThrowsException<DataMisalignedException>(() => JsonSchemaValidator.validateAgainstJsonSchema(ProviderService.getErronousProviders(), "./provider-schema.json"))` but I'm not able to find the docs for `Assert.ThrowsException`  I usually just use the `ExpectedException` attribute on the test method myself.

Comment: @juharr Yes thanks that's what I was looking for. I see it's not converting the function, it is calling it within an anonymous function. Cheers

Comment: My guess is that `Assert.ThrowsException` expects an `Action` and not a `Action<IList, string>`.

Comment: `ThrowsException()` might also be expecting a params list to pass on to the action. But I can't find a reference for that method in MSDN...

Answer (score 1):

To indicate that an exception is expected during test method execution you can make use of the `[ExpectedException]` attribute on top of the test method.

```
[TestClass]
public class JsonSchemaValidatorTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(DataMisalignedException))]
    public void ShouldThrowOnBadPhoneNumber()
    {
        JsonSchemaValidator.validateAgainstJsonSchema(ProviderService.getErronousProviders(), "./provider-schema.json");
    }
}
```